# How to create an updating nav bar>

Tags: html, css

How do I create a nav bar that will update on one page and transfer to all, similar to a CSS style sheet?

Say I have
a nav bar and I want to add content to it from one page but don't want to go and update 400 pages?

Thanks guys!

Comment: With this level of detail, elance.com is your best bet

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get HTML content from a single file into multiple pages. Here are a few:

#### server-side processing

Write the navbar code in one file, then have the server include it as part of each page. For example, in PHP, you'd do something like:

```
<?php include 'nav.php'; ?>
```

#### static site generator

Use a tool to preprocess source files into HTML. These tools are good for reducing per-page boilerplate. [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is one such tool, which is used in GitHub pages. There are [many](https://staticsitegenerators.net/), so pick whichever one you like.

#### iframe

Write the navbar code in one file, then use an `iframe` tag to have each page load it.

```
<iframe src="nav.html"></iframe>
```

#### script

This is probably not the best way, but you can include a `script` tag instead of an `iframe` to make the styling easier. Have the script generate the navigation, for example, by calling `document.write` with the HTML code.

page.html:

```
<script src="nav.js"></script>
```

nav.js:

```
document.write('<nav>...</nav>');
```